# Accessing a property in one ViewModel from another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I want main viewmodel to have a certain list, and then access from many other viewmodels.

For example, in MainViewModel.cs I will have a list of 50 numbers,
then in NumListViewModel.cs, I'd like to access it in order to show it as a list, and in AddNumViewModel.cs I'd like to be able to update that list.

It's been suggested that I use events / evenaggerator, which I did, but unfortunately, for all I know all I can do with it is send a num from one view to another and tell it to update the list, but the problem is, as the program grows, I will need to have a lot of subscribers in the main view model, and when something actually happens I will have to "publish" events according to the number of subscribers which makes it even harder to maintain.

I also found another answer, instructing to create an instance of anotherVM within the mainVM, with a parameter set to "this" which is a reference to the mainVM.
It works, but then again, it could get quite long.

**So my question is, is there a *better* way to access a property from another VM?

Like literally have the an instance of the class that holds the list in the mainVM, and then just be able to update / access it from the other VMs, without having to explicitly program which VM can. Would make life so much easier.**

In your answer, please try to avoid suggesting frameworks.
Although there are some really good ones, I want to be able to do at least that by myself.

For example:

MainVM.cs:

```
public class MainVM
{
    List lst = new List(); //Let's just say it's full...
}
```

OtherVM.cs:

```
public class OtherVM
{
    lst.Add(3);
}
```

*PS: Yes I know it has been asked already, and yes I have done my research, BUT I the answers I found are too 'static', I guess?*

Comment: Use Prism to resolve instance of your MainViewModel.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want *direct* access to the list from an external ViewModel, then your options are to:

1. Pass the List to the OtherVM as a constructor argument or public property.  Then the OtherVM can treat it like a member.
2. Pass the MainVM to the OtherVM as a constructor argument or public property.  Then the OtherVM can access the List by first accessing the MainVM.

Example:

```
public class MainVM
{
    public List<XX> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class OtherVM
{
    public MainVM TheMainVM { get; set; }

    public OtherVM(MainVM theMainVM)
    {
        TheMainVM = theMainVM;
        
        // Access the MainVM's list 
        TheMainVM.MyList.Add(stuff);            
    }
}
```

3. Give the MainVM a static property called "Default" or "Instance," so you can access the static instance of MainVM from within OtherVM, without assigning it as a member field.

Example:

```
public class MainVM
{
    private static MainVM _instance = new MainVM();
    public static MainVM Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public List<XX> MyList { get; set; }
    //other stuff here
}

//From within OtherVM:
MainVM.Instance.MyList.Add(stuff);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Option #3 did the job! Options 1 and 2 work fine, but as the project grows, I will have to pass the instance/list more than once, so I guess this is not a good practice for large-scale applications.

Comment: @BTownTKD I know this question is somewhat old but I have a problem. I have tried your code but in the reverse order. i.e. I have declared Instance property on OtherVM and I want to access it in mainVM. I dont get any errors but when I access any property of OtherVM in MainVM I dont get the value of that property. I mean I get null instead of that property's value.

Comment: You'll want to post that as a new question.

Comment: @BTownTKD could you post an example of the approach in #2? How exactly do I pass the list/object as a ctor argument?

Comment: @BTownTKD I have a  problem with the 3 rd option in the following scenario: In the constructor of `MainVM` I am calling `OtherVM` constructor. In OtherVm constructor, I have used the `Instance` property. In this case Instance is null.

Comment: @Keerthivel this sounds like it should be a new question, about resolving order of initialization between two inter-dependent/coupled objects.